# Create a array of array keys within a serialised array.

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I am querying a WP DB to get the following:

userid 
collection_name 
collection_data (serialized array)

I run the following foreach loop:

```
foreach($result as $row){
$row->collection_name;
$cleandata = unserialize($row->collection_data);
```

The print_r of $cleandata gives me the following arrays:

```
Array
(
[7] => Array
    (
        [ExerciseID] => 7
        [Description] => Description?!
        [Sets] => 12
        [Reps] => 12
        [Load] => 12
        [Rest] => 12
        [Tempo] => 12
    )

)
```

From this I need to create an array of ExerciseID's so I can put them into the following WP_query.

```
$the_query = new WP_Query(array('post__in' => $ids, 'post_type' => 'exercise','posts_per_page' =>'4000')); ?>
```

I have tried running another foreach within the foreach `$result as $row` however I am getting pretty stuck with it.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your PHP version? In 5.5, it is very easy to call [`array_column($cleandata, 'ExerciseID')`](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

Comment: So I would do `$ids = array_column($cleandata, 'ExerciseID');` ?

Comment: Yes, _if_ you have PHP 5.5+. Otherwise, use Mark's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this-

```
$ids = array();
foreach($result as $row)
{
  $row->collection_name;
  $cleandata = unserialize($row->collection_data);

  foreach($cleandata as $data)
  {
      $ids[] = $data['ExerciseID'];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have PHP >= 5.5 and so can't use [array_column()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php), then use

```
$result = array_map(
    function($value) { 
        return $value['ExerciseID'];
    },
    $cleanData
);
```